# Calculating YTD change with dates as column headers

Tags: python

my table looks something like this:

| Sector | 1/1/2022 | 5/1/2022 | 6/1/2022 | 1Y Min |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 10 | 05 | 12 | 05 |
| Y | 18 | 20 | 09 | 09 |
| Z | 02 | 09 | 12 | 02 |

I want to add a new column "YTD change" such that values of the new column is calculated using the formula: (Value as of the latest date - Value as of first available date of the year)

I want to keep the formula dynamic such that it gets updated whenever a column with a new date is available since the placement of the column is likely to shift with new data.

For eg:-

| Sector | 1/1/2022 | 5/1/2022 | 6/1/2022 | 1Y Min | YTD Chg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | 10 | 05 | 12 | 05 | 2 |
| Y | 18 | 20 | 60 | 09 | 40 |
| Z | 02 | 09 | 12 | 02 | 10 |

Comment: What have you tried so far? And FWIW: why is YTD Chg 40 in Y column? Shouldn't this be 42?

Comment: You should add what you have tried before posting this otherwise people just doing your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime 
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Sector": ["X", "Y", "Z"],
    "1/1/2022": ["10", "18", "02"],
    "5/1/2022": ["05", "20", "09"],
    "6/1/2022": ["12", "60", "12"],
})


def add_YTD_chg(data):
    datetime_formatting = "%d/%m/%Y" # check if this formatting is correct. Might be using MM/DD/YYYY?

    invalid_date_columns = ["Sector", "1Y Min"] # declare here cols which are not date-related

    sorted_datetimes = sorted([ # convert to datetime object and sort
        {"datetime":datetime.strptime(i, datetime_formatting), "col_name":i}
        for i in data.columns if i not in invalid_date_columns
    ], key=lambda x: x["datetime"])

    if len(sorted_datetimes) < 2: return # not enough dates to compare "oldest" to "newest"
    
    oldest = sorted_datetimes[0]
    newest = sorted_datetimes[-1]

    data["YTD_Chg"] = data[newest["col_name"]].astype(int) - data[oldest["col_name"]].astype(int)

add_YTD_chg(df)

print(df)
# >>>   Sector 1/1/2022 5/1/2022 6/1/2022  YTD_Chg
# >>> 0      X       10       05       12        2
# >>> 1      Y       18       20       60       42
# >>> 2      Z       02       09       12       10
```

My approach here was to extract all date columns, convert them to a `datetime` object (note here that you need to also remember the name of the column), and then sort by datetimes. What you then do is you create the new column based on the values of the newest and oldest columns.

Some things to note:

- I added a check to make sure there were at least two columns to compare. If there were not two columns to compare it exits the function. You might want to do this differently.
- I assumed you're using the date format `DD/MM/YYYY`. If this assumption was incorrect you might want to edit the `datetime_formatting` variable to reflect this.

Hope this helps!